# How to keep code base and database schema in synch?

Tags: database, visual-studio, orm, tfs, schema

So recently on a project I'm working on, we've been struggling to keep a solution's code base and the associated database schema in synch (Database = SQL Server 2008).

Database changes occur fairly regularly (adding columns, constraints, relationships, etc) and as a result it's not uncommon for people to do a 'Get Latest' from source control and 
find that they also need to rebuild the database as well (and sometimes they forget to do the latter).

We're not using VSTS: Database Edition (DataDude) but the standard Visual Studio database project with a script (batch file) which tears down and recreates the database from T-SQL scripts.  The solution is a .Net & ASP.net solution with LINQ to SQL underlying as the ORM.

Anyone have ideas on an approach to take (automated or not) which would keep everyone up to date with the latest database schema?

Continuous integration with MSBuild is an option, but only helps pick up any breaking changes committed, it doesn't really help in the scenario I highlighted above.

We are using Team Foundation Server, if that helps..

Comment: oye!  this is such a pain.  Especially if there is data that NEEDS to be in the tables too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok although its not the entire solution, you should include an assertion in the Application code that links up to the database to assert the correct schema is being used, that way at least it becomes obvious, and you avoid silent bugs and people complaining that stuff went crazy all of the sudden.

As for the schema version, you could use some database specific functionality if available, but i personally prefer to declare a schema version table and keep the version number in there, that way its portable and can be checked with a simple select statement

Comment: That's not a bad idea.  I was with you on the second part - running the unit tests would quickly reveal of the schema was out of synch (each schema change is paired with an updated unit test), but the first part is interesting.

Comment: You probably should also provide a source file, in whatever languages you use that is checked into source every time, in which the current schema version is defined, that way people can access the version info however they need to, assuming you don't control the database adaptor code.

Answer (score 4):

We try to work forward from the creation scripts.

i.e a change to the database is not authorised unless the script has been tested and checked into source control.

But this assumes that the database team is integrated with your app team which is usually not the case in a large project...

(I was tempted to answer this "with great difficulty")

EDIT: Tools won't help you if your process isn't right.

Comment: What tools do you use for source control? How often in the source control schema "built" on the server?

Comment: SVN, but it doesn't matter if you don't have a factory (Cruise Control etc.)

We have a central "test" server which serves as our CI heartbeat, a nice sanity check that code still works.

Comment: This is a good answer and pretty much what we're following, but Rob Gould's answer actually closed the gap for us.  Voted up though :)

Answer (score 1):

have a look at DB Ghost - you can create a dbp using the scripter in seconds and then manage all your database code with the change manager. www.dbghost.com

This is exactly what DB Ghost was designed to handle.

Comment: Is this much different from Red Gate's SQL Tools Suite?

Comment: I've used DbGhost for 10 years and it's never let me down. The support they isprovide is second to none. Innovartis really understand change management IMO over the RedGate tool.

Answer (score 0):

We basically do things the way you are, with the generation script checked into source control as well.  I'm the designated database master so all changes to the script itself are done through me.  People send me scripts of the changes they have made, I update my master copy of the schema, run a generate scripts (SSMS) to produce the new DB script, and then check it in.  I keep my copy of the code current with any changes that are being made elsewhere.  We're a small shop so this works pretty well for us.  I realize that it probably doesn't scale.

Comment: That's pretty much how things work at the moment on the project :)  I suppose I could alert people when schema changes are committed... Though usually it doesn't affect everyone equally.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using Visual Studio Database Professional Edition, then you will need another tool that can break the database down into its elemental pieces so that they are managable and changeable in an easier manner.

I'd recommend seriously considering [Redgate's SQL tools](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql_tools_overview.htm) if you want to maintain sanity over all your database changes and updates.

- [SQL Packager](http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Packager/index.htm)
- [SQL Multi Script](http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Multi_Script/index.htm)
- [SQL Refactor](http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Refactor/index.htm)

Comment: We've broken down each object into it's own source file so we can maintain version control per table/stored proc.. etc

Comment: If you can manage it all without use of software/automation tools, power to you.

Comment: It's still early days - we'll need Red Gate's suite once the project matures more (and we get production quality test data).

Answer (score 0):

Use a tool like [RedGate SQL Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Compare/index.htm) to generate the change schema between any given version of the database. You can then check that file into source code control

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this question: [dynamic patching of databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252972/dynamic-patching-of-databases). I think it's similar enough to your problem to be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this problem is simple. Define everything as XML, and make sure that both the database, the ORM and the UI are generated from this XML, no exceptions. That way, you can use code generation tools to quickly regenerate the database creation script, which will alter your schema while (hopefully) preserving some data. It takes some effort to do, but the net result is well worth it.